# How to create a sub dataframe from a dataframe using specific columns

Tags: geopandas, filter, geodataframe

I have a dataframe that has more fields/columns than I want, so I am trying to create a sub dataframe that only has certain fields/columns. The following throws a

> TypeError: '(['uniqueid'], ['PARCEL_ID'], ['LAND_USE_T'],
>   ['PROP_IND_T'],['Bldg_Sq_Ft'],
>   ['GEOID'], ['CensusPop'], ['HU_Pop'])' is an invalid key

```
feat_df = gpd.read_file(state_gdb, layer=join_feat)
new_df = feat_df[['uniqueid'], ['PARCEL_ID'], ['LAND_USE_T'], ['PROP_IND_T'], ['Bldg_Sq_Ft'], ['GEOID'], ['CensusPop'], ['HU_Pop']]
```

What is the easiest way to create a sub dataframe with only the specific columns I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the square brackets between the column names, in regular pandas that is what is done for making a dataset subset.

```
new_df = feat_df[['uniqueid','PARCEL_ID', 'LAND_USE_T', 'PROP_IND_T', 'Bldg_Sq_Ft', 'GEOID', 'CensusPop', 'HU_Pop']]
```

Comment: Dont forget geometry column or new_df will be a pandas dataframe and not a geodataframe

Answer (score 2):

You pass one list with the column names you wish to keep:

```
new_df = feat_df[['uniqueid', 'PARCEL_ID', 'LAND_USE_T', 'PROP_IND_T', 'Bldg_Sq_Ft', 'GEOID', 'CensusPop', 'HU_Pop']]
```